# PgAdmin blocked on the application start screen Loading pgAdmin 4 v7.4

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, pgadmin-4, windows-11

I have already reinstalled posgresSQL several times and every time it gets stuck on the screen at startup and only appears the text Loading pgAdmin 4 v7.4....
I checked the Windows registry editor to reset the value of " HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.jsContent Type " to " text/javascript " and this does not solve the error either.

I have looked for some other solution apart from resetting the value to "text/javascript" and I have not seen any other, any help I appreciate it.

Comment: See this [pgAdmin4 7.4 issue](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMa%3DN%3DN242m0L%3DDKvtuP7hiLX2rU6fHUZqD8fB0Pg3s4PdgYKA%40mail.gmail.com).

Answer (score 0):

I posted this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76735202/2985691) yesterday, downgrading to v7.3 should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, I uninstalled pgadmin and installed the previous version and the problem is solved